# How set 2 different y-axes at the save level?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I try to make one plot as below.

But my 2 y-axes are NOT in different level. Also, I can not set left Y-axis "WD" in "red"

Is there anyone can help me to figure out those two problems ?

Many Thanks !

```
DLPM10$hours <- as.integer(gsub('.* |:.*', '', DLPM10$date))

dt <- group_by(DLPM10, hours) %>%

summarise(WD = mean(WD_DOUGLAS, na.rm = TRUE), WS = mean(WS_DOUGLAS, na.rm = TRUE))

par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)

barplot(height = dt$WD, axes=FALSE, border =NA,space = 0.4,ylim=c(0,370),
    col="red",xlab = 'Hour', ylab = 'WD', main = "Dougals Red Cross")

axis(2, ylim=c(0,370),col="red",col.axis="red",col.lab="red",las=1) 

par(new = TRUE)

plot(dt$hours, dt$WS,axes = FALSE, bty = 'n',pch= 19,xlim = c(-.35, 23.35),
 ylim=c(0,5), col="blue", xlab = '', ylab = '')

axis(4, 0:5, col="blue", col.axis="blue",las=1)

mtext('WS', dt$WS,col="blue", side = 4, line = 2)

axis(1, 0:23, pos = -0.2)

legend("topleft",legend=c("WS","WD"),bty = "n", 
   bg = par("bg"),
   text.col=c("blue","red"),pch=c(19,15),
   col=c("blue","red"),horiz= T,text.width= 0.01)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,4))
plot(1, axes=FALSE, ylab='', ylim=c(0,370), xlim = c(-.35, 23.35), col=0)
mtext("WD", side=2, line=3, col="red", cex=1)
mtext("WS", side=4, line=3, col="blue", cex=1)
axis(1, 0:23, pos = -0.2)
axis(2, ylim=c(0,370),col="red",col.axis="red",col.lab="red") 
axis(4, at=c(0:5)*370/6,labels=0:5, col="blue", col.axis="blue",las=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry it does not work for me. I found if I change barplot(height = dt$WD, axes=FALSE, border =NA,space = 0.4,ylim=c(-10,370),
    col="red",xlab = 'Hour', ylab = 'WD', main = "Dougals Red Cross") The two axis are close now but. I am not 100% if there are at the same level.